# Are there general solutions to quadratic, 2D, continuous, time-invariant dynamical systems?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, quadratics, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics

I am a bit new to dynamical systems and don't know my way around terminology, so have had a hard time answering this for myself.

I know the basics of theory for 2D linear, time-invariant systems, i.e.,
$$
\dot{x}=a_1x+a_2y \\
\dot{y}=b_1x+b_2y
$$
I know that there are explicit exponential solutions, and a ton of theory about fixed points and stability.

I'm wondering if there is any equivalent theory out there for the next higher-degree systems, i.e.,
$$
\dot{x}=a_1x+a_2y+a_3x^2+a_4y^2+a_5xy \\
\dot{y}=b_1x+b_2y+b_3x^2+b_4y^2+b_5xy
$$

I get that this is non-linear, so not nearly as simple. But are there any general solutions or time-scales/eigenvalue-equivalents? Is there a standard approach to looking at this as pieced-together linear approximations? Is there a *name* for this kind of system or its study that I can look up?

Thanks very much!

Comment: One thing to try is to first tackle the case of "homogeneous polynomials", i.e. the case without the $a_1x+a_2y$ terms on the right hand side of $\dot x$ and similarly for $\dot y$. But, frankly, I'm not at all sure how to do that case.

Comment: If enough parameters are zero so that the equations become uncoupled, you get Bernoulli equations, or more generally Riccati equations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A useful search phrase is “quadratic planar vector fields”.

Despite much research, there are still many open problems concerning such systems. For example, [Hilbert's sixteenth problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_sixteenth_problem) asks for an upper bound for the number of limit cycles of systems of the form $\dot x = p(x,y)$, $\dot y = q(x,y)$, where $p$ and $q$ are polynomials of degree at most $n$. It is known that any given such planar polynomial system can have at most finitely many limit cycles; this was first claimed by Dulac, but it turned out much later that his proof was flawed, and a correct proof was found around 1990. But it's still unknown whether that finite number can be arbitrarily large or not (when you consider *all* possible systems of that form), even in the simplest nontrivial case $n=2$ (quadratic polynomials, as in your question). See, for example, the Scholarpedia article [Limit cycles of planar polynomial vector fields](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Limit_cycles_of_planar_polynomial_vector_fields).

There are of course special cases where you can say more, like the famous Lotka–Volterra predator–prey model where you have a constant of motion which causes all nontrivial trajectories to be periodic, but there's no hope of finding a general solution formula which covers all quadratic systems.

Comment: That is tremendously helpful, both the context summary and the examples.